# Google Font similar to Blippo

Tags: google-font-api

Im looking for a font family on google fonts that is similar to Blippo-black or Bauhaus 93. Does anyone know the name of a similar font. It must be available on google fonts. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Erica+One
or https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Allerta+Stencil

Comment: Awesome. Erica-one is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You want this. It's similar, isn't any the same.

http://google.com/fonts/specimen/Erica+One